# VBA If cell is under a certain length, highlight and display message

Tags: excel, vba, highlight

I'm trying to write a Macro that examines a certain column in an Excel spreadsheet looking for entries shorter than 9 characters but greater than 2, and if found, display a message and highlight the cell in which that value was found.  It might happen multiple times.  I have written the following code:

```
Sub Highlight()
Dim c As Range
Dim LR As Integer
Dim intCell As Long
LR = Worksheets("Basket").Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
For intCell = 1 To 8
For Each c In Range("G20:G" & LR).Cells
    If Len(c.Value) < 9 And Len(c.Value) > 2 Then
    MsgBox "One or more of the codes is invalid.  Correct the highlighted values."
    c.Cells(intCell).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If
Next
Next
End Sub
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what is the difference between actual versus expected behaviour?

Comment: +1 to pnuts suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

Just guessing at what you want to highlight

```
Sub Highlight()
Dim c As Range
Dim LR As Integer
Dim numProbs as long
Dim sht as Worksheet

Set sht=Worksheets("Basket")

numProbs=0
LR = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
For Each c In sht.Range("G20:G" & LR).Cells
    If Len(c.Value) < 9 And Len(c.Value) > 2 Then
        c.entirerow.cells(1).Resize(1,8).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        numProbs=numProbs+1
    End If
Next

if numProbs>0 Then
    msgbox "There were issues with " & numProbs & " rows. See yellow cells"
end if 


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:a10")) Is Nothing Then
     If Len(Target) <= 9 And Len(Target) >= 2 Then
     MsgBox " Length of string is " & Len(Target)
     Target.Font.Bold = True
     End If
End If
End Sub
```

I have used range A1:A10 for the trial.

Answer (score 0):

This will run over all the cells with anything in, colour in the ones out of your range, and warn how many cells are incorrect.

```
Dim sheetName As String
Dim startRow As Integer, startCol As Integer
Dim endRow As Integer, endCol As Integer
Dim row As Integer, col As Integer
Dim c As Integer

sheetName = "Sheet1" 'Your sheetname

With Sheets(sheetName)

    startRow = 1 'start row for the loop
    startCol = 1 'start column for the loop

    endRow = .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row 'Last Used Row
    endCol = .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column 'Last Used Column

    c = 0

    For row = startRow To endRow Step 1 'Loop through rows

        For col = startCol To endCol - 1 Step 1 'Loop through columns

            If Len(.Cells(row, col)) > 2 and Len(.Cells(row, col)) < 9 Then 'If value of cell is wrong

                .Cells(row, col).Interior.Color = vbYellow 'mark cell in red
                c = c + 1

            End If

        Next col
    Next row

    MsgBox "There were issues with " & c & " entries. See yellow cells" 'Warns that there are errors

End With
```